# What is the equivalent of Xamarin MessagingCenter in Flutter?

Tags: xamarin, flutter, dart, xamarin.forms

With `Xamarin`, We usually use [Message-Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send a message to any page when Application is running (start App or app is background).

With `Flutter`, have we any ways that send a message same with [Message-Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) of `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: [Possibility](https://pub.dev/packages/event_bus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, you can use `Channel` to achieve that. 
[image]
[BasicMessageChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/BasicMessageChannel.html) is a similar channel.

**Native part**.

```
    private final Activity activity;
    private final BasicMessageChannel<String> messageChannel;

    static BasicMessageChannelPlugin registerWith(FlutterView flutterView) {
        return new BasicMessageChannelPlugin(flutterView);
    }

    private BasicMessageChannelPlugin(FlutterView flutterView) {
        this.activity = (Activity) flutterView.getContext();
        this.messageChannel = new BasicMessageChannel<>(flutterView, "BasicMessageChannelPlugin", StringCodec.INSTANCE);
        //Set up a message handler to handle messages from Dart
        messageChannel.setMessageHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s, BasicMessageChannel.Reply<String> reply) {//Handle messages from Dart
        reply.reply("BasicMessageChannel：" + s);//Can reply by `reply`
        if (activity instanceof IShowMessage) {
            ((IShowMessage) activity).onShowMessage(s);
        }
        Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Send Dart a message and receive feedback from Dart
     *
     * @param message  Content of the message to send to Dart
     * @param callback Feedback from Dart
     */
    void send(String message, BasicMessageChannel.Reply<String> callback) {
        messageChannel.send(message, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void reply(String s) {

    }
}
```

**Dart Part**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
static const BasicMessageChannel _basicMessageChannel =
const BasicMessageChannel('BasicMessageChannelPlugin', StringCodec());

//Use BasicMessageChannel to receive messages from Native and reply to Native
_basicMessageChannel
    .setMessageHandler((String message) => Future<String>(() {
          setState(() {
            showMessage = message;
          });
          return "receive Native's message：" + message;
        }));
//use BasicMessageChannelsend message to Native And accept Native's reply
String response;
    try {
       response = await _basicMessageChannel.send(value);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Here is blog about it.
https://stablekernel.com/flutter-platform-channels-quick-start/

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching the same implementation in Flutter. So far I haven't found any.

This is my simple implementation

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

abstract class MessagingService {
  void subscribe(Object subscriber, {@required String channel, @required void Function(Object) action});

  void unsubscribe(Object subscriber, {@required String channel});

  void send({@required String channel, Object parameter});
}

class MessagingServiceImpl implements MessagingService {
  static final _map = <String, Map<String, void Function(Object)>>{};

  @override
  void subscribe(Object subscriber, {@required String channel, @required void Function(Object) action}) {
    assert(subscriber != null);
    assert(channel != null);
    assert(channel.isNotEmpty);
    assert(action != null);

    if (!_map.containsKey(channel)) {
      _map[channel] = {};
    }

    _map[channel].putIfAbsent(subscriber.hashCode.toString(), () => action);
  }

  @override
  void send({@required String channel, Object parameter}) {
    assert(channel != null);
    assert(channel.isNotEmpty);

    if (_map.containsKey(channel)) {
      for (final action in _map[channel].values) {
        action(parameter);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void unsubscribe(Object subscriber, {@required String channel}) {
    if (_map.containsKey(channel)) {
      _map[channel].removeWhere((k, v) => k == subscriber.hashCode.toString());
    }
  }
}
```